MATLAB windows graphics
i am in trouble for MATLAB hidden input, i need to have an account manager with users and passwords. The problem is that i can only use basic-MATLAB, i can not assume that the user might have anything more than simple MATLAB. With the only way that i found i can open a window for hidden password, but that, graphically, it's completely different from the rest of my program.
this is the hidden version:

this is the normal version:

As you can see these two are completely different form each other, i would really appreciate any help on how to resolve, if possible. For the visible one i have used the normal inputdlg function, i will paste the code for the hidden function. I am really new in MATLAB so, unfortunately, i am fully lost in here.
function pass = getPasswordNET()
    %# password return value
    pass = '';

    %# hidden figure used to wait for button press
    fig = figure('Visible','off', ...
        'IntegerHandle','off', 'HandleVisibility','off');

    %# create and show the Windows Forms GUI
    [handles,lh] = InitializeComponents();
    handles.frm.Show();

    %# block execution until figure is closed
    waitfor(fig)

    %# remove the listeners
    delete(lh);

    return;

    %# create GUI
    function [handles,lh] = InitializeComponents()
        %# import assembly
        NET.addAssembly('System.Windows.Forms');

        %# form
        frm = System.Windows.Forms.Form();
        frm.SuspendLayout();

        %# textbox
        tb = System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        tb.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        tb.Text = '';
        tb.PasswordChar = '*';
        tb.MaxLength = 20;

        %# button
        bt = System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        bt.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
        bt.Text = 'conferma';

        %# setup the form
        frm.Text = 'Password';
        frm.ClientSize = System.Drawing.Size(250, 45);
        frm.Controls.Add(tb);
        frm.Controls.Add(bt);
        frm.ResumeLayout(false);
        frm.PerformLayout();

        %# add event listeners
        lh(1) = addlistener(bt, 'Click', @onClick);
        lh(2) = addlistener(frm, 'FormClosing', @onClose);

        %# add event listener for textbox key press
        lh(3) = addlistener(tb, 'KeyPress', @onKeyPress);

        %# return handles structure
        handles = struct('frm',frm, 'tb',tb, 'bt',bt);
    end

    %# event handlers
    function onClick(~,~)
        %# get password from textbox
        pass = char(handles.tb.Text);

        %# close form
        handles.frm.Close();
    end

    function onClose(~,~)
        %# delete hidden figure (to unblock and return from function)
        close(fig)
    end

    %# event handler for key press
    function onKeyPress(~, eventData)
        if eventData.KeyChar == char(13) % Check if Enter key is pressed
            onClick(); % Call onClick function
        end
    end
end

